# How to use a function from another file using require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, spotify

No questions that I found on StackOverflow answered this question or gave a solution to my problem.

I am creating an app to use Spotify's API. I am relatively new to JavaScript, but I have been a coder for a long time in other languages, specifically OO languages. I am trying to use OO-esque code in my project for dealing with the API.

I might not properly understand how to do it, but here is my basic understanding.
I have all of the code for dealing with the API in one file called `smartspot.js`. Inside of that file is something that resembles the following.

```
/**
 * Taps into the Spotify API to create a playlist with top songs from artists most like a certain artist.
 * @param {string} _clientId the client ID code given to the user by Spotify.
 * @param {string} _clientSecret the client secret code given to the user by Spotify.
 * @param {string} _redirectUri a Redirect URI that has been white-listed by Spotify.
 * @constructor creates a SmartSpot that can access the Spotify API.
 */
function SmartSpot(_clientId, _clientSecret, _redirectUri)
{
     //initialize the variables (omitted)
     var clientId = _clientId;
         clientSecret = _clientSecret;
     //etc...

     //various irrelevant variables and functions are ommited.
     this.foo = function(param)
     {
         //does stuff    
     };
     //etc...
}
```

Now, I believe that `function SmartSpot(_clientId, _clientSecret, _redirectUri)` is a constructor (as in languages like Java and C++). Correct me if I am wrong. So, assuming that it *is* a constructor, I need to use it in another file: my express "routes" file. It is located in `routes/index.js'.
At the top of the file, I put this

```
var SmartSpot = require('../SmartSpot'); //I have also tried require('../Smartspot.js');
//later on
var smartSpot = new SmartSpot(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri);

//elsewhere
smartSpot.foo();
```

However, the compiler complains to me telling me:

```
TypeError: SmartSpot is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    //etc...
```

What am I missing here? I am using IntelliJ for all this, and it suggests that I need to create a function, so I do, and it creates the constructor/function in the `index.js` file. I want to separate the files to make the code easier to understand and simpler to use.

If there is anything that you need to answer this question that I left out, let me know.

Comment: Will you be using those JavaScript files on an HTML page? If yes, you can include the JS files using <script> tag and you can use functions from one file in another file.

Comment: First of all, Javascript is interpreted, not compiled. You get this message, because you haven't export your function from module, add the following code in SmartSpot js file: `exports = SmartSpot;`.

Comment: @Erick this is done on the server side.

Comment: @AlexanderMac does it matter where that statement is placed? Because I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You can export something, that is already defined. So it must be in the end.

Comment: @AlexanderMac I noticed that a lot of other files I have in the project have `module.exports = ObjectName;` at the bottom, so, I added that to the bottom of my file (as opposed to just `exports = SmartSpot;`), and it "compiled" properly. Btw, what's the proper word in that sentence instead of compile?

Comment: There is no such word, javascript code is executed by demand. So you'll get errors in runtime. There is a few tools, such as jshint which allows to detect a few bugs in code during development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to some help from Alexander Max, after looking around, I noticed that a lot of my other files had `module.exports = Something;`.
This turned out to be the solution. I put `module.exports = SmartSpot;` at the bottom of the `SmartSpot.js` file, and also put `var SmartSpot = require('../SmartSpot');` at the top of the other file. Now, the file is interpreted properly, and I am able to use the functions of it from my routes file.